# Questions about Citymaps on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gps, citymaps

At today's development, I have some new questions and as follows:

1、When I open GPS service，call the method mapView.startUpdatingLocation()，it is locating the current position very well，but if I close the GPS and does not set the default position，is it can locating automatic by network and show an blue arrow in the map?

2、I create a class which implements LocationSource interface and then call
mapView.setLoactionSource and set the locate way is network，but when I open the application to load the map，I found the position is United States. It does not locate the current position where I am. is that right？

3、Sometimes，loading the map too slowly to loading the data timely,  are there offline map to use?

4、In your office website，there some introduce for the region layer like this：

```
 After zooming out a certain amount, the Business Layer will disappear and the Region Layer will appear.  The Region Layer displays a set of hand-picked cities and towns, with a custom image for each place.  Tapping one of the pins will zoom you into that place, giving you an overview of the area.
```

What is mean "the business layer will disappear and the region layer will appear"？I did't find the phenomenon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a developer on the Citymaps SDK, I will do my best to answer your questions.

1) If you use the default location source built into the SDK, it will never find your location with GPS off.

2) If you implement `LocationSource` yourself, it is up to you to determine the user's location and tell the `LocationChangeListener` when the position has changed.  Have a look here at the default implementation of `LocationSource` for more details:  https://bitbucket.org/citymaps/citymaps-android-map-library/src/5a8bafc9638a99c122ba671683299185f9796a48/src/com/citymaps/citymapsengine/CitymapsLocationSource.java?at=master

3) We do not currently have offline maps, but it is a feature we are working on.  It should be released within the next month or so.

4) If you look at the Citymaps application in the Play Store, or the SDK sample,  you will see what this means if you zoom the map in and out.  It is difficult to explain further than what was stated above, so you should check out these two examples and see for yourself.